# How to fetch data and pass. into form and response customername onkeyup or keydown json and php

Tags: php, json, ajax

This is  Mysql DB connection.php

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", 'root', "", "laravel");
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from customers");

    while ($result2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      $data[] = $result2['customername'];
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The json is not responding onKeyup or keydown it is displaying the whole output. But i want to display only the current related matched names on to display. I was new to json and ajax. i think ajax and json both respond the same.

```
<form action="">
    First name: <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
    </form>

    <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>

    <script>
    function showHint(str) {
      var xhttp;
      if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
      }
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "connection.php?q="+str, true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Thanks for your suggestions. All suggestions are welcome.

How pass into form and response on keyup or keydown and related suggestions customername should display down. I am new to JSON and javascript and examples sites. Thanks in advance. All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options;

---

One is that you re-pull all the data in an ajax call by appending the text box input to the SQL query in a `"WHERE name LIKE %" . $input . "%'";` but this will be costly in terms of speed an network traffic.

---

Another option and the one I would opt for, is getting all of the names in a SELECT as you have done, then using RegEx within javascript to filter the results shown.

Here is a good link on using regular expressions.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

---

Edit: 
None of this is tested as I don't have the means to test right now.

For the first example, I am going to assume you are passing the query via the GET and thus in your PHP file you change your code to as follows:

```
<?php
    // Your DB connection
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", 'root', "", "laravel");
    // Initialise the query string
    $qString = "SELECT * FROM customers";
    // Providing a parameter is sent in the GET request to the PHP page, look for names
    // containing that string
    isset($_GET['q']) ? $qString .= " WHERE customername LIKE '%" . $_GET['q'] . "%'" : "";

    $qHandler = mysqli_query($conn, $qString);

    while ($qResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qHandler)) {
      $data[] = $qResult['customername'];
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

So when a request is made via call of showHint(str) it will append that str to the query in a 'like' statement, with the %% wildcards. So you put 'art' in the text box, it will return names like 'bART', 'mARTher', etc.

Comment: Please elborate your answer

Comment: @JBK I have expanded on the comment above, hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks my code is working after modify with your code. Thanks alot Mr. JokerDan

Comment: @JBK No problem! Also remember security can be an issue so using prepare / execute of statements is a safe way to go. Marking as the answer would also be greatly appreciated.